# Error when replace a jar to /wso2am-4.0.0/repository/components/plugins

Tags: wso2-api-manager

After build carbon-apimgt, i get a jar from target with some changes.
Than i replace the exist jar at wso2am-4.0.0/repository/comonents/plugins with my new jar,
and remove backup folder in wso2am-4.0.0. But error happens when
I run the server by command "./api-manager.sh" .

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: Rename the jar with replace  first - to _ and second - to .  It works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the error logs, it's bit hard to guess the exact reason for such behavior, but it can happen due to the following two reasons.

1. A Naming issue. The jars that are found in the plugins directory are used to create a profile this will be added to the classpath. The naming is crucial and you have to rename the new jar exactly as it was before. Otherwise, this jar will not be added to the class patch and it can cause several errors.
2. If you are using an updated wso2am distribution (With U2 update for paid customers), and you built the jar from the [initial release tag- 9.0174](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v9.0.174) in the wso2/carbon-apimgt repository. For U2 updates, there are several bug fixes and security fixes are sent and the code is updated from its initial release. These updates could contain some breaking changes such as interface changes, change or addition of new methods and variables etc. When you build from the initial release, this will create an outdated jar and it will not work and you can get several errors such as NoClassDefFound exceptions etc.
3. You have built the jar from a wrong carbon-apimgt tag. This will create mismatches between jars and can lead to different errors.

Comment: I use the dependency repo below: 

[1]. carbon-apimgt （v9.0.174）

[2]. product-am （v4.0.0）

the source code was clone by tag, which matched the version  from pom.xml. I build [1] first, and then [2].  My changed code was base on tag 9.0.174, so, is it right?

Comment: Can you share the error that you received?

Comment: I'm sorry that the log are removed. Next time when happend i save it